# Debugging 404 on GAE production server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am receiving a 404 error for every file of my GAE project on the live server and I'm unsure of the next debugging steps

My directory structure is as follows:

```
| /project
|____ /build
|________ index.php
|________ other_project_files.php
```

Here are the relevant configuration handlers in app.yaml:

```
application: alex-young
version: 2
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

default_expiration: "7d 0h"

skip_files:
- (.*/)?.*/node_modules/.+ 
- (.*/)?.*/src/.+
- (.*/)?.*/gruntfile\.js
- (.*/)?.*/todo\.txt

handlers:
# - url: /robots.txt
#   static_files: robots.txt
#   upload: robots.txt 

- url: /Alexander\ Young\ -\ Resume.pdf
  static_files: build/Alexander\ Young\ -\ Resume.pdf
  upload: build/Alexander\ Young\ -\ Resume.pdf

- url: /css
  static_dir: build/css

- url: /img
  static_dir: build/img  

- url: /js
  static_dir: build/js  

- url: /partials
  static_dir: build/partials
  application_readable: true

- url: /templates
  static_dir: build/templates
  application_readable: true  

- url: /utils
  static_dir: build/utils
  application_readable: true

- url: /mustache
  static_dir: mustache
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: build/\1

- url: /
  script: build/index.php
```

The logs simply show a 404 error and no other information. My entire project loads fine on my local machine's MAMP and GAE test servers. I have no idea where to look for errors. Does GAE provide any more details other than Logs?

Comment: What happens when you remove the first URL? Does your index.php get hit?

Comment: @Bruyere No it does not

Comment: I mimicked what you have above. Project with my app.yaml, a folder with 2 files named index and other project (i know it was a place holder) and the code you linked worked on GAE servers. Could you show your whole app.yaml file?

Comment: @Bruyere I added it above

Comment: @Bruyere Ok I am an idiot, I apologize for wasting your time. I am using Push-to-deploy with git. Before I setup GAE, I was not pushing the build directory to my repo. Once GAE was linked to my git repo, it obviously couldn't find the build directory.